# Titlepage: Two Textboxes next to each other at bottom of page

Tags: latex3

i´m trying to design the title page for my thesis. 
I have the Title centred at the top. Now i want two columns with text on the bottom of the page.
Something like:

Supervisor:____Prof. Smart_______________Author:____Mr. Me
Faculty:_______Economics_______________Studenid:_1234567

(Sorry, iam just getting started with Latex and Markdown as well).
\twocolumn doenst seem appropriate and I got stuck with \tinypage.
Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
% This goes in the preamble of your document
\usepackage{tabularx}



\vspace*{\fill} % Push the following table to the bottom of the page
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llXll}
Supervisor: & Prof. Smart & & Author:     & Me \\
Faculty:    & Economics   & & Student ID: & 1234567 \\
\end{tabularx}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole bunch of different ways. If by "elegant" you mean elegant LaTex, I wouldn't worry: it's a titlepage so you can just adjust as needed. If by elegant you mean "looks good", I personally like the first tabular version, which aligns sensibly and **doesn't** use the full text width. But it's really just a matter of taste.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

  \begin{center}
    \Large
    Life, the Universe, and Everything:\\The Problem Solved

    \bigskip

    \normalsize
    Thesis submitted in partial satisfaction of the requirements for
    the degree of Master of the Universe

    \medskip
    27 March 2019
  \end{center}
  \vfill

  \noindent Professor: Professor Smart\hfill Author: Magnificent Me

  \noindent Faculty: Faculty of Economics\hfill ID: 666-6666-666

  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{rlp{1cm}rl}
    Professor: & Professor Smart & & Author: & Magnificent Me \\
    Faculty: & Faculty of Economics & & ID: & 666-6666-666
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    Professor: Professor Smart

    Faculty: Faculty of Economics
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \flushright
    Author: Magnificent Me

    ID: 666-6666-666
  \end{minipage}

\begin{center}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    Professor: Professor Smart

    Faculty: Faculty of Economics
  \end{minipage}%
  \qquad
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    Author: Magnificent Me

    ID: 666-6666-666
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rlXrl}
      Professor: & Professor Smart & & Author: & Magnificent Me \\
      Faculty: & Faculty of Economics & & ID: & 666-6666-666
    \end{tabularx}
\bigskip

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    Professor: Professor Smart

    Faculty: Faculty of Economics
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    Author: Magnificent Me

    ID: 666-6666-666
  \end{minipage}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent Professor: Professor Smart

    \noindent Faculty: Faculty of Economics

    \noindent Author: Magnificent Me

    \noindent ID: 666-6666-666
\end{multicols}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Titlepage]